# how to change the value of system files without opening them?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Is there any way to change "PermitRootLogin"'s value in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` via one command in the terminal ?

I want to change the values of this file without opening it,and change "PermitRootLogin"'s value from yes to no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's perfectly possible to do it with `sed`, match for the line and change the value:

```
sed -i '/^PermitRootLogin/s/yes/no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

- `^PermitRootLogin` matches the line starting with `PermitRootLogin`
- `s/yes/no` changes the value of the option from "yes" to "no"

Answer (score 1):

> I want to change "PermitRootLogin"'s value from yes to no.

In this case I'd use Perl (i.e. something that works with fields and that can edit in-place; Sed fails at the first one and AWK fails at the second one):

```
sudo perl -i -lane '/^PermitRootLogin/?print("@F[0] no"):print($_)' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

```
% grep ^PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config                                                     
PermitRootLogin without-password
% sudo perl -i -lane '/^PermitRootLogin/?print("@F[0] no"):print($_)' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
[sudo] password for user: 
% grep ^PermitRootLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config                                              
PermitRootLogin no
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change them with sed, use the -i option

```
sed -i -e 's/old/new/g' file
```

See man sed for detials

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "without opening the file in an editor", that's possible.

For example, you can use `sed` to replace regular expression patterns with fixed strings:

```
sed 's/REGEX-PATTERN/REPLACE-WITH-THIS-STRING/' /PATH/TO/FILE
```

The above command will print the content of the file with substituted lines. It will **not perform the substitutions, just print a "preview"**!
To actually apply the substitutions after having checked them, use the `-i` ("substitute in place") flag:

```
sed -i 's/REGEX-PATTERN/REPLACE-WITH-THIS-STRING/' /PATH/TO/FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Any program that in any way deals with files, has to have to issue `open()` as well as `read()` system calls, which can be verified with `strace`. Opening a file without those system calls is impossible

Your question appears to ask whether a file can be edited without text editor. That is possible, as others have shown. My little contribution here is the following:

```
awk '/^PermitRootLogin/{$2="yes"}1' /etc/ssh/sshd_config > /tmp/sshd_config && mv /tmp/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Basically with AWK , we find appropriate line, replace field 2 , which is "no" to "yes", output everything to tmp file and replace original with tmp file using `mv`.

Remember that ownership of that config file belongs to root , so you would need `sudo` access ( add `sudo` before `mv` )

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '/^PermitRootLogin/s/yes/no/|x' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

1. `s` substitute
2. `x` save and close